# Why do lattice structures absorb more photon frequencies than single atoms?

Tags: photons, crystals

I'm trying to understand why the liquid-like structure of glass is necessary for it to be transparent.

Comment: relevant  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_and_translucency